# How do i get a reference to my contentView from my PreferencesActivity class?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to put a background image on my preference activity and i want to make it dynamically.

This is my code (on the OnCreate of the PrefrenceActivity class):

```
    // Set the background image
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.spash_bk);
    BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(bmp);
    bitmapDrawable.setAlpha(100);
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) *** here i need the layout ***
    layout.setBackgroundDrawable(bitmapDrawable);
```

What i am missing is: who can get a reference to the layout so i can perform the action?

Thanks in advance,
Lior

Answer (score 1):

You must give an ID in .xml class in layout

e.g

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/my_layout_id"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center">
```

...

after that Clean and build you project.

then replace the line

> LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) ** here i need the layout **

with

> LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)  findViewById(R.id.my_layout_id);